# WebRTC - flash client

Tags: flash, video, chat, webcam, webrtc

I have a website where one user may chat to another, using their webcam, via WebRTC.

Chrome supports WebRTC, as does Firefox's nightly build. However, some visitors use Internet Explorer, and thus are unable to use the chat. Currently, we use Flash to enable one to one chat. Microsoft are not bringing WebRTC to IE.

I would like to ditch Flash where possible, and wondered if there was a way for IE users to use a Flash client, which behaved as a WebRTC client, enabling them to talk to the other website visitors who use Chrome.

I can't see anything online about such a client. I realise this is not an elegant patch, but short of Microsoft changing their mind about WebRTC, I can't see any other option.

1. Does such a thing exist?
2. If not, is there a technical reason why it shouldn't?

Comment: Were you able to find anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but WebRTC works with [Google Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) in IE.

You can see an example of it in action at https://gittogether.com.